# Let $p$ be a probability dist. on $X\times Y$ s.t. marginal of $p=\mu$. Is $p\otimes p(A\times (Y\times Y)) = \mu\otimes \mu(A)$ true?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be complete and separable metric spaces with Borel probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$, respectively. Now take any distribution $p$ on $X\times Y$ so that the marginal of $p$ on $X$ is $\mu$ and the marginal on $Y$ is $\nu$. That is, we have

$\begin{align} p(A\times Y) &= \mu(A) \textrm{ for any measurable }A\subset X, \textrm{and}\ \\ p(X\times B)&=\nu(B) \textrm{ for any measurable }B\subset Y.\end{align}$

We can define a probability distribution on $(X\times Y)^2$ by $p\otimes p$, the product measure.

There is a natural bijection between $(X\times Y)^2$ and $X\times X\times Y\times Y$ by
\begin{equation}
s: X\times X\times Y\times Y\to (X\times Y)^2, s(x,x',y,y')=(x,y,x',y').
\end{equation}
Clearly, this is a continuous bijection, so it is measurable (and the inverse is also measurable).

Now, take any measurable set $A\subset X\times X$. $s(A\times (Y\times Y))$ is a measurable set in $(X\times Y)^2$.

**Question:**

**Is it true that $p\otimes p(s(A\times (Y\times Y)))=\mu\otimes \mu(A)$?**

**My Attempt:**
I feel like it is true, but I am not sure what to do. What I did first is to write the LHS as an integral:

$\begin{align} p\otimes p(s(A\times (Y\times Y))) = \int_{X\times Y}\int_{X\times Y}1_{s(A\times (Y\times Y))}(x, y,x',  y')dp(x,y)dp(x',y')\end{align}$

We have that $1_{s(A\times (Y\times Y))}(x, y,x',  y') = 1$ if and only if $(x,x')\in A$ by definition, so $1_{s(A\times (Y\times Y))}(x, y,x',  y')=1_{A}(x,x')$ for any $y,y'$. So,

$\begin{align}\int_{X\times Y}\int_{X\times Y}1_{s(A\times (Y\times Y))}(x, y,x',  y')dp(x,y)dp(x',y') &=\int_{X\times Y}\int_{X\times Y}1_{A}(x,x')dp(x,y)dp(x',y') \\ &\color{red}{=^{?} \int_{X}\int_{X}1_{A}(x,x')d\mu(x)d\mu(x')}\\ &=\mu\otimes \mu(A)\end{align}$

The line in red is the part I am not sure how to justify. Intuitively this should be true since the integrand does not depend on $y,y'$ anymore, but I can't prove it. Is the above argument sound, and how do I make it better?

Comment: Look up Fubini's Theorem. Tonelli's Theorem also applies here. They describe the conditions under which you are allowed to interchange the order of integration.

Comment: @forgottenarrow I know Fubini, but what do we do after exchanging the order?

Comment: @forgottenarrow I don't assume that $p=\mu\otimes \nu$.  I just have that the marginals of $p$ are $\mu$ and $\nu$.  $p=\mu\otimes \nu$ corresponds to the special case when the marginals are independent.

Comment: My bad, I misread your post and thought that $p$ was just a product of $\mu$ and $\nu$. In this case I would take a more fundamental approach. It should be easy to show that $\nu\otimes \nu(s(A\times (Y\times Y))) = \mu\otimes\mu(A)$ if $A = A_1\times A_2$ where $A_1,A_2$ are Borel sets in $X$. Then you can just use the Dynkin $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem to show that the equality holds for all A in borel(X\times X)